# Spring WS sendSourceAndReceiveToResult method via POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

How to use `sendSourceAndReceiveToResult()` from  [Using Spring Web Services on the Client](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) with custom serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't correct. Any SOAP request is `POST` over HTTP transport.

If we take a look to the `WebServiceTemplate#sendSourceAndReceiveToResult` source code, we'll see:

```
 Boolean retVal = doSendAndReceive(uri, transformer, requestPayload, requestCallback,
                new SourceExtractor<Boolean>() {

                    public Boolean extractData(Source source) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                        if (source != null) {
                            transformer.transform(source, responseResult);
                        }
                        return Boolean.TRUE;
                    }
                });
```

Pay attention to the `doSendAndReceive` internal method invocation. Any high-level `WebServiceTemplate#` API do the same. And on the backgound the `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender` is used as default SOAP transport, where `connection.setRequestMethod(HttpTransportConstants.METHOD_POST);` is used to build `HttpUrlConnection`.

That's all.

Comment: Thank's for your answer!